# Как заставить ORACLE корректно добавлять нод в xml с xmlns?

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

При добавлении одного XMLTYPE в другой с xmlns обнаружил проблему.

```
-- Пример:
DECLARE
  Document XMLTYPE;
   docInfo XMLTYPE;
BEGIN

  Document := xmltype.createxml(
  '<request xmlns="http://www.bla-bla.net/qqq/schemas/">
      <a>1</a>
     <b>123.00</b>
  </request>');

  /*
  -- Вариант 1
  docInfo := xmltype.createxml(
  '<zzz>
      <ttt>0.00</ttt>
      <mmm>qqq</mmm>
  </zzz>');
  --*/

  -- Вариант 2
  docInfo := xmltype.createxml(
  '<zzz xmlns="http://www.bla-bla.net/qqq/schemas/">
      <ttt>0.00</ttt>
      <mmm>qqq</mmm>
  </zzz>');
  --*/

   SELECT XMLQUERY('declare default element namespace "http://www.bla-bla.net/qqq/schemas/"; 
                    copy $tmp := . modify (
                                           for $i in $tmp/*
                                               return insert node $dif
                                           as last into $i )
                    return $tmp'
                   PASSING Document, docInfo as "dif"
                   RETURNING CONTENT )
   INTO Document
   FROM dual;
   dbms_output.put_line( Document.EXTRACT('/').getClobVal() );
END;
```

Вариант 1. (см. Пример)
Если в docInfo НЕ ПРОПИСАТЬ xmlns, то результирующий XML
будет иметь вид:

```
<request xmlns="http://www.bla-bla.net/qqq/schemas/">
  <a>1</a>
  <b>123.00</b>
  <zzz xmlns="">   <!--  Вот она проблема!  -->
    <ttt>0.00</ttt>
    <mmm>qqq</mmm>
  </zzz>
</request>
```

Вариант 2. (см. Пример)
Если в docInfo ПРОПИСАТЬ xmlns, то результирующий XML
будет иметь вид:

```
<request xmlns="http://www.bla-bla.net/qqq/schemas/">
  <a>1</a>
  <b>123.00</b>
  <zzz xmlns="http://www.bla-bla.net/qqq/schemas/">  <!--  Вот она  проблема!  -->
    <ttt>0.00</ttt>
    <mmm>qqq</mmm>
  </zzz>
</request>
```

Вопрос: Как заставить ORACLE добавлять нод с xmlns, чтобы в результате получить:

```
<request xmlns="http://www.bla-bla.net/qqq/schemas/">
  <a>1</a>
  <b>123.00</b>
  <zzz>
    <ttt>0.00</ttt>
    <mmm>qqq</mmm>
  </zzz>
</request>
```

Вариант преобразования с помощью XSL не предлагать.
Сейчас так и сделано.

Спасибо.

Comment: Возможно, что бы легче было ответить, стоить сделать вопрос более лаконичным? Пример кажется сейчас не минимальным.

Comment: Дык куда уж лаконичнее? Как заставит ORACLE корректно добавлять нод в xml с xmlns? Пример выше.

Comment: @decyrus по мне так это как раз хороший пример MCVE.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT XMLElement("Employee", 
                  XMLAttributes('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' AS
                                  "xmlns:xsi"),
                  XMLForest(employee_id, last_name, salary)) AS "RESULT"

FROM hr.employees
   WHERE department_id = 10;
```